# Most efficient way to convert 8 hex chars into a 4-uint8_t array?

Tags: c++, integer, hex

I have a `const char*`, pointing to an array of 8 characters (that may be a part of a larger string), containing a hexadecimal value. I need a function that converts those chars into an array of 4 `uint8_t`, where the two first characters in the source array will become the first element in the target array, and so on. For example, if I have this

```
const char* s = "FA0BD6E4";
```

I want it converted to

```
uint8_t i[4] = {0xFA, 0x0B, 0xD6, 0xE4};
```

Currently, I have these functions:

```
inline constexpr uint8_t HexChar2UInt8(char h) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<uint8_t>((h & 0xF) + (((h & 0x40) >> 3) | ((h & 0x40) >> 6)));
}

inline constexpr uint8_t HexChars2UInt8(char h0, char h1) noexcept
{
    return (HexChar2UInt8(h0) << 4) | HexChar2UInt8(h1);
}

inline constexpr std::array<uint8_t, 4> HexStr2UInt8(const char* in) noexcept
{
    return {{
        HexChars2UInt8(in[0], in[1]),
        HexChars2UInt8(in[2], in[3]),
        HexChars2UInt8(in[4], in[5]),
        HexChars2UInt8(in[6], in[7])
    }};
}
```

Here's what it will look like where I call it from:

```
const char* s = ...; // the source string
std::array<uint8_t, 4> a; // I need to place the resulting value in this array
a = HexStr2UInt8(s); // the function call does not have to look like this
```

What I'm wondering, is there any more efficient (and portable) way do do this? For example, is returning a `std::array` a good thing to do, or should I pass a `dst` pointer to `HexChars2UInt8`? Or are there any other way to improve my function(s)?

The main reason I'm asking this is because I will likely need to optimize this at some point, and it will be problematic if the API (the function prototype) is changed in the future.

Comment: Efficient in what sense ? Is this part of your code really performance-critical ?

Comment: @Paul R: It is very likely that `HexStr2UInt8` will be called around 5000 times per second, perhaps much more.

Comment: I think that is already pretty much "efficient" (performance-wise). So what I think you're looking for is basically  "elegant" code that *looks* good. Is that so?

Comment: Assuming non-ANSI platform portability isn't an issue, what you have now is pretty damn efficient. Are you just looking for something shiny  ?

Comment: by the way your array stores int NOT hex values ... your assumption is totally wrong.

Comment: @Zyx - You know that a standard desktop computer performs *billions* of instructions per second? Doing 5000 function calls like this is not going to be noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add parallelism, as the HexChar2Uint8 can access 8 characters at the same time. It's probably faster to load non-aligned 64-bit value once than 8 chars one by one (and to call the conversion function)

```
hexChar2Uints(uint8_t *ptr, uint64_t *result)  // make result aligned to qword
{
  uint64_t d=*(uint64_t*)ptr;
  uint64_t hi = (d>>6) & 0x0101010101010101;
  d &= 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f;
  *result = d+(hi*9);  // let compiler decide the fastest method
}
```

The last stage has to be done as OP suggested, just reading from modified "string":

```
for (n=0;n<4;n++) arr[n]=(tmp[2*n]<<4) | tmp[2*n+1];
```

The chances are slim that this can be considerably speeded up. The `<< 4` operation could be injected to hexChar2Uints making that parallel too, but I doubt it can be made in less than 4 arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient, i.e. the fastest way to do the conversion is probably to set up a table of 65536 values for every possible pair of 2 characters, and to store in the valid ones their conversions.

If you store them as unsigned chars you won't be able to catch errors so you'll just have to hope you get valid input. If you store the value type as bigger than unsigned char you'll be able to use some kind of "error" value but checking if you get one will be an overhead. (The extra 65536 bytes probably isn't).

What you have written is probably efficient enough too though. Of course once again you are also not checking for invalid input and will get a result anyway.

If you keep yours I might change:

```
((h & 0x40) >> 3) | ((h & 0x40) >> 6)
```

which seems to be a substitute for

```
( (h & 0x40) ? 10 : 0 )
```

I can't see how my expression is less efficient than yours and is probably clearer in intention. (Use `0xA` rather than 10 if you insist on hex)

Comment: His solution is neither portable nor maintainable, and should be avoided at all costs.  A 65536 byte table could be used, but doing the conversion character by character, using a 256 byte table, allows an out of bounds value in the table for error checking, and offers significantly better locality, and so may be faster.  (A 256 byte table will fit in cache; a 65536 might not.)

Answer (score -2):

There are several approaches possible.  The simplest and the
most portable is to break the characters down into two character
`std::string`, using each to initialize an `std::istringstream`,
set up the correct format flags, and read the value from that.
A somewhat more efficient solution would be to create a single
string, inserted whitespace to separate the individual values,
and just use one `std::istringstream`, something like:

```
std::vector<uint8_t>
convert4UChars( std::string const& in )
{
    assert( in.size() >= 8 );
    std::string tmp( in.begin(), in.begin() + 8 );
    int i = tmp.size();
    while ( i > 2 ) {
        i -= 2;
        tmp.insert( i, 1, ' ');
    }
    std::istringstream s(tmp);
    s.setf( std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield );
    std::vector<int> results( 4 );
    s >> results[0] >> results[1] >> results[2] >> results[3];
    if ( !s ) {
        //  error...
    }
    return std::vector<uint8_t>( results.begin(), results.end() );
}
```

If you really want to do it by hand, the alternative is to
create a 256 entry table, indexed by each character, and use
that:

```
class HexValueTable
{
    std::array<uint_t, 256> myValues;
public:
    HexValueTable()
    {
        std::fill( myValues.begin(), myValues.end(), -1 );
        for ( int i = '0'; i <= '9'; ++ i ) {
            myValues[ i ] = i - '0';
        }
        for ( int i = 'a'; i <= 'f'; ++ i ) {
            myValues[ i ] = i - 'a' + 10;
        }
        for ( int i = 'A'; i <= 'A'; ++ i ) {
            myValues[ i ] = i - 'a' + 10;
        }
    }
    uint8_t operator[]( char ch ) const
    {
        uint8_t results = myValues[static_cast<unsigned char>( ch )];
        if ( results == static_cast<unsigned char>( -1 ) ) {
            //  error, throw some exceptions...
        }
        return results;
    }
};

std::array<uint8_t, 4>
convert4UChars( std::string const& in )
{
    static HexValueTable const hexValues;
    assert( in.size() >= 8 );
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> results;
    std::string::const_iterator source = in.begin();
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++ i ) {
        results[i] = (hexValues[*source ++]) << 4;
        results[i] |= hexValues[*source ++];
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: convert4UChars would work but not nearly as efficient as what Zyx 2000 already has.

Comment: Your table lookup implementation is buggy.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk What Zyx 2000 has isn't at all portable, and only works by chance.  It's a perfect example of how not to write code.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Could you explain then, why my code isn't portable?

Comment: @Zyx2000 It makes all sorts of assumptions concerning the bit patterns in the encodings.

Comment: @Zyx2000 And of course, it's also completely unreadable and unmaintainable.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk There are a couple of small typos, which should be obvious and are trivial to fix.  The basic principle works, however.  And works correctly, on all conformant C++ implementations, and for all possible input.

Comment: @JamesKanze programming is a balancing act of different requirements.  In some circumstances performance trumps readability and maintainability.  The only potential issue I see with Zyx 2000's code is the fact that the input to HexStr2UInt8 could be less than 8 characters or a NULL ptr.  As we are seeing code snippets and not final production code.  We can assume that he/she is checking for those before calling the conversion function.  Even then the speed requirements could be so absolute that occasional failures could be more tolerable than the loss of performance due to checking.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk Performance can be important, but readable versions can be just as performant as what he's written.  (I suspect that my second version above would be faster on most machines; the difference would, in any case, be minimal.)  And regardless of the performance constraints, you still have to make the code correct and readable.